# How can I test mongoose session transactions. Error: MongooseError: Connection 1 was disconnected when calling `startSession

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am testing out mongoose atomic transactions. While creating a user, I perform all operations under a transaction. This works just fine in the development environment but fails when running tests

```js
// db connection
const { MongoMemoryReplSet } = require('mongodb-memory-server');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing') {
  const replSet = new MongoMemoryReplSet({
    replSet: { storageEngine: 'wiredTiger' },
  });
  await replSet.waitUntilRunning();
  const uri = await replSet.getUri();

  mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
  mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
  mongoose.connect(uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
} else {
  mongoose.connect(settings.uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    replicaSet: 'rs',
  });
}

// user controller
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

controller.createUser = async (req, res) => {
  const session = await mongoose.startSession();
  session.startTransaction();

  const user = new User({username: req.body.username})
  try {
    await user.save({ session });
    await session.commitTransaction();
    ...
  } catch (err) {
    await session.abortTransaction();
    throw new Error(err)
  } finally {
    session.endSession();
  }
  ...
}

// test
describe('user api routes', () => {
  it('should create a user', async () => {
    const res = await request(app).post('/api/v1/users').send({});
})
```

> npm test

```
Error MongooseError: Connection 0 was disconnected when calling `startSession
```

When I remove the transaction code and session, it works just fine.
How can I ensure that while running tests, I can start a session and not close the connection?

Comment: What documentation are you following?

Comment: Hey, did you resolve this?

Comment: @MTA not yet. I opted for a sql db as it became a little complicated to add new documents and update the existing ones to match the new database structure.

Comment: @D.SM a couple for sure.
- https://medium.com/cashpositive/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-mongodb-transactions-with-mongoose-5bf8a6e22033
- https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html

Comment: See https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/10008 regarding your usage which is incorrect but I don't know why mongoose is disconnecting your connections.